# I cannot fetch the data from AWS Amplify Data Models using React-native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, react-hooks

I have an issue when I try to fetch the data from AWS Amplify data model into to my app one of the screens then I can't get it (Price and Name), But I analyzed my code, so my point of view I have never do any mistake in the code so please help me to solve this issue as well.

bellow I provide three files code, and which are so helpful for Identify errors as well

screens>busket>index.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { View,Text, StyleSheet, FlatList  } from "react-native";
import {AntDesign} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import BusketListItem from "../../components/BasketListItem";
import { useBasketContext } from "../../contexts/BasketContext";
import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";


const Basket = () => {
  const { restaurant, basketDishes, totalPrice } = useBasketContext();

  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <Text style={styles.name}>{restaurant?.name}</Text>

      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", marginTop: 20, fontSize: 19 }}>
        Your items
      </Text>

      <FlatList
        data={basketDishes}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <BusketListItem basketDish={item} />}
      />

      <View style={styles.separator} />

     
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    paddingVertical: 40, // temp fix
    padding: 10,
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "600",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  description: {
    color: "gray",
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  quantity: {
    fontSize: 25,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    marginTop: "auto",
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  quantityContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgray",
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    paddingVertical: 2,
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
});

export default Basket;
```

src>components>BasketListItem>index.js

```
import { View,Text, StyleSheet, FlatList  } from "react-native";



const BasketListItem = ({basketDish}) => {
    console.log(basketDish);

    return(
        <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.quantityContainer}>
        <Text>{basketDish.quantity}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: '600' }}>{basketDish.Dish.name}</Text>

      <Text style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>{basketDish.Dish.price}</Text>
    </View>
    
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical:15,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,

    },
    quantityContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        paddingVertical: 2,
        marginRight: 10,
        borderRadius: 3,
    },
    
});

export default BasketListItem
```

src>context>BasketContext.js

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";
import { Basket, BasketDish } from "../models";
import { useAuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

const BasketContext = createContext({});



const BasketContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { dbUser } = useAuthContext();
  

  const [restaurant, setRestaurant] = useState(null);
  const [basket, setBasket] = useState(null);
  const [basketDishes, setBasketDishes] = useState([]);

  const totalPrice = basketDishes.reduce(
    (sum, basketDish) => sum + basketDish.quantity * basketDish.Dish.price,
    restaurant?.deliveryFee
  );


  useEffect(() => {
    DataStore.query(Basket, (b) =>
      b.restaurantID.eq(restaurant?.id).userID.eq(dbUser?.id)
    ).then((baskets) => setBasket(baskets[0]));
  }, [dbUser, restaurant]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (basket) {
      DataStore.query(BasketDish, (bd) => bd.basketID.eq(basket?.id)).then(
        setBasketDishes
      );
    }
  }, [basket]);
  
  

  const addDishToBasket = async (dish, quantity) => {
    // get the existing basket or create a new one
    let theBasket = basket || (await createNewBasket());

    // create a BasketDish item and save to Datastore
    const newDish = await DataStore.save(
      new BasketDish({ quantity, Dish: dish, basketID: theBasket.id })
    );

    setBasketDishes([...basketDishes, newDish]);
  };

  const createNewBasket = async () => {
    const newBasket = await DataStore.save(
      new Basket({ userID: dbUser.id, restaurantID: restaurant.id })
    );
    setBasket(newBasket);
    return newBasket;
  };


 
  

  return (
    <BasketContext.Provider
      value={{
        addDishToBasket,
        setRestaurant,
        restaurant,
        basket,
        basketDishes,
        totalPrice,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </BasketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default BasketContextProvider;

export const useBasketContext = () => useContext(BasketContext);
```

above I mentioned my issue as well, below I provide some snipping for the better understanding.

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result:
[image: Actual Result]

Amplify Data Model:
[image: Data Modeling]